# How to place a \sim over \equiv similar to \simeq and \cong?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators, superscripts

As the question states, I want a tilde over \equiv similar to \simeq and \cong commands. To be more specific, they tilde needs to be closer to the `\equiv` symbol.

I've tried using `stackrel` and `DeclareMathOperator*` but they place it way too high.

I've even tried to place it under empty space over `\equiv` as math operator as in

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\eq}{\equiv}
\newcommand{\poly}{\eq^{\stackrel{\sim}{\hspace*{2em}}}}
```

yet still no luck.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A straightforward modification of the code for `\cong` in `fontmath.ltx`

```
\DeclareRobustCommand
  \cong{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@vereq\sim}} % congruence sign
\def\@vereq#1#2{\lower.5\p@\vbox{\lineskiplimit\maxdimen\lineskip-.5\p@
    \ialign{$\m@th#1\hfil##\hfil$\crcr#2\crcr=\crcr}}}
```

Here is the new `\ccong` (change the name to your liking):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ccong}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@verequiv\sim}}
\newcommand{\@verequiv}[2]{%
  \lower.5\p@\vbox{
    \lineskiplimit\maxdimen
    \lineskip-.5\p@
    \ialign{%
      $\m@th#1\hfil##\hfil$\crcr
      #2\crcr
      \equiv\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A=B\equiv C\cong D\ccong E$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,stackengine}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\eq}{\equiv}
\newcommand{\poly}{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.5pt}{\equiv}{\sim}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \equiv A \simeq A \cong A \poly A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Here is a version that works for smaller math styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,stackengine,scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\eq}{\equiv}
\newcommand{\poly}{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.5\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\equiv}{\SavedStyle\sim}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \equiv A \simeq A \cong A \poly A$\par
$\scriptstyle A \equiv A \simeq A \cong A \poly A$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A \equiv A \simeq A \cong A \poly A$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the error: "! LaTeX Error: File `listofitems.sty' not found."

Comment: @OsamaKawish Can get `\listofitems.tex`, `listofitems.sty` and `listofitems_en.pdf` at http://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems